# Can't customize default Powershell colors and settings when running from Context Menu shortcut

Tags: powershell, customization

I configured a custom font/size/color scheme for Powershell by right clicking on the title bar and selecting `properties`.

[image: Customs]

The settings persist if I open Powershell from the start menu search.

Unfortunately they don't when I invoke Powershell from a right click context menu:

[image]

[image]

Con someone possibly instruct me on how to make my changes permanent irrespective of how PS is launched?

Thank you very much for any assistance!

Comment: On which OS are you working ? It seems to work as you expect on windows 10.

Comment: I got it kind of working but now I'm confused. If I open it via C:\Users\futur\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell I get one visual style. If I directly open it from "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" I get another visual style. By editing the settings after directly opening the exe from System32 it fixed my problem. But I'd really like to know why the start menu shortcut and the exe itself have separate preferences.

Comment: You're running the second instance as Administrator and the first one as yourself..

Comment: Ahhhh! That makes sense. Thanks.